Connecting SQL Developer 24 to MS SQL Server 2016/2019
I have Oracle's SQL Developer 24.3 (uses Java 17 in the background) and want to connect to MS SQL Servers 2016 and 2019. Using third party jTDS driver (which kinda officially supports MS SQL Server up to 2012) I can connect to MSSQL2016 but not MSSQL2019. jTDS is obsolete and one cannot rely on it. (Tools->Preferences->Database->Third Party JDBC Drivers)
But I would like to connect to MSSQL databases using Microsoft's JDBC driver. I tried mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre11.jar but SQL Developer does not recognize this JDBC driver and does not offer SQL Server connection at all.
How to solve this issue?

i'm guessing the ms driver doesn't correctly specify the following jar manifest entries: Specification-Title: JDBC Specification-Version: ... Specification-Vendor: ... which seems both jtds and mysql do, you can probably edit it in and try. Although, there surely are better clients that oracle developer for sql server?

Oracle is not known for its good support of things that don't pay an Oracle license (that includes MySQL). The official docs say this only works with jTDS. There are far better cross-database IDEs, like DBeaver (open source) or JetBrains DataGrip (paid, but free for students, non-profits etc, very cheap for individuals and very, very good)

we dont' allow 'just any jdbc' source, the support for jtds is explicitly defined - i'm looking into what's up for sql 2019. Note, this support is only to help you migrate that sql 2019 database to an oracle one. is that your goal here as well?

Silly question perhaps... if it's using Java 17 have you tried the .jre17 version of the .jar file? (Based on the file lists I see you might have to use the 11.2 version of the driver.)

@AlwaysLearning - not silly question, but yes, I tried .jre17 version, it does not work either.

@thatjeffsmith - my intention is to use only one tool for connecting to Oracle, MS SQL and MySQL in the same time.

@srbot then i would rec looking at VS Code and get best extensions for those

@siggermannen - I tried DBeaver many years ago and went to SQL Developer because I mostly worked on Oracle database. Now when I have to work with three or four databases I'm going to use DBeaver. I see it is now very advanced IDE.
